Variable Value (Hex Code ) not binding with Tailwind css in React(TypeScript)
In the code given below when i try to use the colorPalatte in register the value is binding in themes(usestate) but in the class im not able to use it like this : className={bg-[${theme.?primaryColor}]} but when i declared the value like this -->     primaryColor: "bg-[#222831]", its working . is their any way to use the only the value and bind it with the tailwind css ?
ColorPalatte.tsx
export interface colorPalatteType {
  primaryColor: string;
  secondaryColor: string;
  tertiaryColor: string;
  quartinaryColor: string;
}

export default function ColorPalatte(): colorPalatteType {
  return {
    primaryColor: "bg-[#222831]",
    secondaryColor: "393E46",
    tertiaryColor: "00ADB5",
    quartinaryColor: "EEEEEE",
  };
}


Register.tsx
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import CssDoodleUnicode from "../../../components/backgroundAnimation/CssDoodleUnicode";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  AuthResponse,
  AuthenticationService,
} from "../service/AuthenticationService";
import axios from "axios";
import { USER_REGISTER_URL } from "../../../systemutils/SystemConstants";
import SignWithGoogleButton from "../../../components/SignWithGoogleButton";
import { VerificationPopUs } from "../../../components/common/PopUs/VerificationPopUs";
import ColorPalatte, {
  colorPalatteType,
} from "../../../systemutils/ColorPalatte";
interface request {
  emailAddress: string;
  password: string;
}

function register() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState<colorPalatteType>();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState<string>("");
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [authResponse, setAuthResponse] = useState<AuthResponse>({
    isStatus: false,
    message: "",
  });
  const signUpButtonTrigger = async () => {
    setDisabled(true);
    const validationResponse = AuthenticationService(email, password);
    setAuthResponse(validationResponse);
    setMessage(validationResponse.message);
  };

  const doodleTimeOut = () => {
    document.querySelectorAll("css-doodle").forEach(function (o: any) {
      o.update();
    });
  };
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (authResponse.isStatus) {
      try {
        const body: request = {
          emailAddress: email,
          password: password,
        };
        const register = async () => {
          await axios
            .post(USER_REGISTER_URL, body)
            .then((response) => {
              if (response.data.status) {
                setDisabled(true);
                VerificationPopUs("Verification Message Send to your Email");
                setTimeout(() => {
                  navigate("/");
                }, 2500);
              }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              if (error.response.data.errorCode === "1003") {
                setMessage("Email Already Exist");
              }
            });
        };
        register();
      } catch (error) {
        setMessage("Server not Reachable");
      }
    }
  }, [authResponse]);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    const genDoodleID = setInterval(doodleTimeOut, 150);

    return () => {
      document.body.style.overflow = "unset";
      clearInterval(genDoodleID);
    };
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    const getTheme = ColorPalatte();
    setTheme(getTheme);
  }, []);
  console.log(theme?.primaryColor)
  return (
    <>
      {/* <div className="absolute  w-[100%] select-none overflow-hidden">
        <CssDoodleUnicode></CssDoodleUnicode>
      </div> */}
      <motion.div
        className="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 bottom-1/2  right-1/2 flex items-center justify-center text-lg "
        initial={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0 }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1 }}
        transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
      >
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center px-5 sm:px-0">
          <div className={`flex ${theme?.primaryColor} rounded-lg shadow-lg border border-green-400 overflow-hidden w-[50dvh]`}>
            <div className="w-full p-8">
              <p className="text-gray-100 font-semibold text-center text-2xl">
                Create New Account
              </p>
              <p className="text-red-600">{message}</p>
              <div className="mt-4">
                <label className="block text-gray-200  text-sm font-bold mb-2">
                  Email Address
                </label>
                <input
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setEmail(e.target.value);
                  }}
                  className="text-gray-800 border border-gray-300 rounded py-2 px-4 block w-full focus:outline-2 focus:outline-blue-700"
                  type="email"
                  required
                />
              </div>
              <div className="mt-4 flex flex-col justify-between">
                <div className="flex justify-between">
                  <label className="block text-gray-200 text-sm font-bold mb-2">
                    Password
                  </label>
                </div>
                <input
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setPassword(e.target.value);
                  }}
                  className="text-gray-700 border border-gray-300 rounded py-2 px-4 block w-full focus:outline-2 focus:outline-green-700"
                  type="password"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="mt-8">
                <button
                  disabled={disabled}
                  onClick={() => signUpButtonTrigger()}
                  className="bg-green-600 transition-colors duration-200 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 w-full rounded-lg hover:bg-green-700"
                >
                  Sign up
                </button>
              </div>
              <SignWithGoogleButton />
              <div className="mt-4 flex items-center w-full text-center">
                <span className="text-xs text-gray-500 capitalize text-center w-full">
                  Don&apos;t have any account yet?
                  <Link to={"/authentication/"} className="text-green-700">
                    {" "}
                    Sign In
                  </Link>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </motion.div>
    </>
  );
}

export default register;


im expecting to use the hexcode which is retuned from color palatte and bind it with the tailwind bg-[${value}]

Does this answer your question? Trouble with Dynamic Color in Tailwind Component

As per the documentation:

The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as complete unbroken strings in your source files.
If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
Don’t construct class names dynamically
<div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>

In the example above, the strings text-red-600 and text-green-600 do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
Always use complete class names
<div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>


You could:

Have the entire class in the variable like you have already done so.
Use the style attribute, like:
export default function ColorPalatte(): colorPalatteType {
  return {
    primaryColor: "#222831",

<div … style={{ backgroundColor: theme?.primaryColor }}>




Thanks for the answer , so that was the problem when i tried as full it was working. but i find another way i used scss for the themes and generated custom classes similar to tailwind and included in the index.scss
